# Retrieve the author of the last-committed revision of a file in CVS

Tags: cvs

Using CVS, I have a list of files. I want to retrieve the user that committed the last revision of each of these files. Is there an easy way to do this? CVS’s usage doesn’t appear to give an easy way of retrieving the author of a particular revision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

`cvs log -N foo.c | head -n 30  | grep -m 1 "author:"`

or

`cvs log -N -r{version} foo.c | grep "author:"`

And then further parse the output line to get just the author info.